# How to apply in real time the change of appcelerator application

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I'm new builder of appcelerator studio, so I'm building a simple app and I test it throught my Android device, so if I try to build the code, running (in debug mode) on my device, this works, but if I try to change the code for examle:

I have write a wrong description:

```
$.label.text="Okkk"
```

and I change when the debug is running in this:

```
$.label.text="OK"
```

to see this change I must stop running debug, rebuild the application.

This is the best way or there is another mode then if I change the code, it in real time are rebuilding in my device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you build an app, Click on 'Enable Liveview' icon from the Studio top toolbar. This will do the magic for you.

[image]

Comment: And if you are using the Open Source `ti` instead of `appc` you can use: TiShadow (https://github.com/dbankier/TiShadow) or faster-titanium (https://github.com/CureApp/faster-titanium iOS only at the moment). I'm currently using faster-titanium for a project and it's working fine - only some times you need to restart it

Answer (score 1):

If you use LiveView, it's faster, you don't need to re-build the app every time, it does that for you, changing only the piece of code that you change.

http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/02/how-the-appcelerator-platforms-liveview-saves-developers-hours-each-day/

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/LiveView